# Can't Modify the PFLogInViewController logInButton title

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, parse-platform, pfloginviewcontroller

i'd been using Parse.com services in my new iOS app development, so far it works like a charm, however i'd been trying to modify the login button text from the PFLogInViewController using code in both swift and objective-C but the results are the same (NONE!)

**ObjC**

```
 [logInViewController.logInView.logInButton setTitle:@"Test!" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
 logInViewController.logInView.logInButton.titleLabel.text = @"Another Test";
```

**Swift**

```
 self.logInView.logInButton.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "loginBtn"), forState: UIControlState.Normal )
```

Comment: Did you sub-class the PFLVC as discussed in the "Further View Customization" section here? https://parse.com/docs/ios_guide#ui-login/iOS

Comment: Yes i did try subclassing and by just creating an instancia of it but the behaviour persists, thanks for your comment!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally figure out how to solve this, you must apply the changes in the event

**Swift**

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews()
{
    println("didLaoutSubView")
    self.logInView.logInButton.setTitle("Test", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    self.logInView.logInButton.setTitle("Test", forState: UIControlState.Highlighted)
}
```

**ObjC**

```
-(void)viewDidLayoutSubviews
{
    [self.logInView.logInButton setTitle:@"Test!" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    self.logInView.logInButton.titleLabel.text = @"Another Test";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

That did not work for me, because of the way I present the view.  This is how I did it:

```html
 PFLogInViewController *logInViewController = [[PFLogInViewController alloc] init];
            
 [logInViewController setDelegate:self]; // Set ourselves as the delegate
            
[logInViewController.logInView.logInButton setTitle:@"Sign In" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

[self presentViewController:logInViewController animated:YES completion:NULL];
```

Comment: hey pal, thanks for sharing you code, since parse is mostly dead i did not develop any more apps on it, however did learn tons about UIButton and it's behaviors developing this app.